# Get data from entry set and fill up a bean

Tags: java

I have a entry set

Eg:

```
[
    fromyear=2009,toyear=2010,student=Sam,
    fromyear1=2010,toyear1=2011,student1=Don,
    fromyear2=2011,toyear2=2012,student2=Mike
]
```

Now I have a Class Student:

```
class StudentDtls{
    String fromyear,
    String toyear,
    String student
}
```

I am iterating through above entry set, how do i make sure

```
fromyear=2009,toyear=2010,student=Sam come in one object of StudentDtls,
fromyear1=2010,toyear1=2011,student1=Don in second object of StudentDtls and 
fromyear2=2011,toyear2=2012,student2=Mike in third object of StudentDtls  .
```

Also the suffixes may go till 10 or 20 . Eg entry set may have fromyear10,toyear10 and student10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using reflection as next:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("fromyear", "2009");
map.put("toyear", "2010");
...

// Map that will contain the StudentDtls instances with the suffix as key
Map<String, StudentDtls> objects = new HashMap<>();
// The pattern used to extract the field name and the suffix if it exists
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z]+)(\\d*)");
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // Create the matcher
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry.getKey());
    matcher.find();
    // Get the first group corresponding to the field name
    String fieldName = matcher.group(1);
    // Get the second group corresponding to the suffix, "" if it is not provided
    String objectId = matcher.group(2);
    // Get the current object corresponding to the suffix found
    StudentDtls object = objects.get(objectId);
    if (object == null) {
        // It has not been created so far so we create it
        object = new StudentDtls();
        objects.put(objectId, object);
    }
    // Get the field corresponding to the extracted field name
    Field field = StudentDtls.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    // check if the field is accessible
    if (!field.isAccessible()) {
        // Make it accessible to be able to modify its value
        field.setAccessible(true);
    }
    // Set the value of the field for the current object
    field.set(object, entry.getValue());
}
// Print the object created
System.out.println(objects.values());
```

**Output:**

```
[
    StudentDtls{fromyear='2009', toyear='2010', student='Sam'}, 
    StudentDtls{fromyear='2010', toyear='2011', student='Don'}, 
    StudentDtls{fromyear='2011', toyear='2012', student='Mike'}
]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for solution , also how can the solution be applied if my class instance variables have different names than the field names received from the set?

Comment: If you have different names you will have to change the logic of this code otherwise It won't work as it relies on them but at least you see the logic with this code snippet